# How do I convert my service to run with AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to convert the things executed in my service to AsyncTask to make it better. However, I'm new to this concept and I've been having trouble setting it up (not knowing what to put where).
This service is executed on `onHandleIntent` once a button from `MainActivity` is pressed.

the part that should run in doInBackground() (collectData() gets the data usage info about apps in the phone):

```
    Utils.d("On Handle Inent Called -- Will collect Data");
    newStartTime = intent.getLongExtra("startTime",0);
    newEndTime = intent.getLongExtra("endTime",0);
    dataUsage = collectData();
```

the part that runs onPostExecute() (starts a new activity that lists the apps and their data usage):

```
    isWifi = intent.getBooleanExtra("isWifi",true);
    Intent intentActivity = new Intent(this, DataDisplayActivity.class);
    intentActivity.putExtra("dataUsage",dataUsage.toString());
    intentActivity.putExtra("isWifi",isWifi);
    startActivity(intentActivity);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need an async task if you are already using `IntentService`?

Answer (score 0):

```
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Utils.d("On Handle Inent Called -- Will collect Data");
                newStartTime = intent.getLongExtra("startTime",0);
               newEndTime = intent.getLongExtra("endTime",0);
               dataUsage = collectData();
               return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
                super.onPostExecute(showsForBucket);
                isWifi = intent.getBooleanExtra("isWifi",true);
                Intent intentActivity = new Intent(this, DataDisplayActivity.class);
                intentActivity.putExtra("dataUsage",dataUsage.toString());
                intentActivity.putExtra("isWifi",isWifi);
                startActivity(intentActivity);
            }
        }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```